# Problems jQueryUI latest version with tooltip widget

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip, joomla4

For the first here for posing a question. I've already learned a lot from the site.

My problem is that i can't get the jQuery UI widget tooltip working on my site.
I'm on joomla 4 with an RSJoomla template (RSJuno).

In my custom.js file i've added this code for diplaying images full size:

```
//Photos fullscreen
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("img").click(function(){
                this.requestFullscreen()})});
```

Works well.

Now i'm trying this code:

```
//Tooltip on fotos
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery( "div" ).tooltip({
  content: "Awesome title!"
});
});
```

Not working at all. Content is just a test text! If i use "img" it isn't working either. Nothing shows up.

This code (from internet) as a test is also working well.
(Div and img are both used to test so i'm aware of the difference in the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    // Detect when the mouse is over a div with the mouseover() method  
    jQuery( "div" ).mouseover(function ( event ) { 
        // Make the div under the mouse grey and taller
        jQuery( "div" ).tooltip({
        content: "Awesome title!"
//By the way the tooltip is NOT showing the content text//
});
        jQuery( "#" + event.target.id ).css({ 
           "background-color" : "lightgrey",
           "height" : "8em"
        });
    }); 
    
    // Detect when the mouse moves away with the mouseout() method 
    jQuery( "div" ).mouseout(function ( event ) { 
        // Return the size and color of the div to its original state
        jQuery( "#" + event.target.id ).css({
           "background-color" : "white",
            "height" : "4em"
        });
    });
});
```

I would like to have a code which integrates this 2 codes into 1 simple one that does the following:

1. on mouseover displaying tooltip "Click for fullscreen" on  tag;
2. as mouse moves away, hide the tooltip.

Whatever i'm trying in no way i get the tooltip to display, no mather to what  i connect it: "img" "div"....etc. And thus combining the 2 leads to nothing.

The big code is working in so far that the css styled tooltip is shown, but at a fixed place (center of the div) and ONLY on a specially created div in the page. NOT on the "img" tag.

If a attach this long code with css to the special created div it's shows only the content of the tag title on the div and not the custom text.
If i delete the title tag from the div nothing shows.

Could it be a conflict with the template code?

I have a RSJoomla template and through custom  tags in the template i'm loading the necessary libraries as follows:

```
<link href="/templates/rsjuno/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/templates/rsjuno/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/templates/rsjuno/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

From inspecting my page i see that this is well loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/rsjuno/css/custom.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="/templates/rsjuno/js//jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="/templates/rsjuno/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/templates/rsjuno/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/templates/rsjuno/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" /> </head>
<body class="site">
....
```

After spending lots of hours i'm out of ideas. Lots of different codes i found on internet for the tooltip didn't work either.
For example (on the youtube video its working well):

```
    jQuery("img").tooltip({
    track:true,
    content:"Whow"
    });
    });
```

I need to use jQuery instead of $ to avoid "$ is not a function" error.

So please help if you can.

Ps i cannot provide a link to the site because its developped on localhost.

Thanks

NEW INFO  I've used this working fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/2vnt9a0h/32/) in exact copy on my website and still get a standard layout tooltip.  See this screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJq7k.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe try to clear browser cache and reload? ... the fiddle example is not showing the standard tooltip for me on Firefox v1.0.8.